# C#- Checking two fields of different forms in one application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, itext

I have names of fields as

```
List<string> names = af.GetSignatureNames();
```

where as I input in a combobox as

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(new combodata("Signature 1"));
comboBox1.Items.Add(new combodata("Signature 2"));
comboBox1.Items.Add(new combodata("Signature 3"));
```

and retrieve the same in a function as

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();//combobox value taken
```

The problem is I have combobox on form 2 and list of string names on form 1 in a pdf file I want to compare both the fields as I have some data to be added to the corresponding signature dictionary on a click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

Use a public static variable on one or the other to gain access to it from the other form.

```
class myForm1
{    
   public static List<string> myList;

   //code here
}

class myForm2
{
   myForm1.myList //do something with it
}
```

Comment: the class specifies are different terey are partial classes